# How Do You Fix Error Code 0x8007045D When Installing Windows 7 Ultimate?

Tags: windows-7

I was installing windows 7 ultimate because my computer had no operating system and it was all going fine in till when it was on the 2nd step. It stayed at 0% for a while then I get this error message "Windows cannot install the required files. Make sure all files required for installation are available, and restart installation. Error Code 0x8007045D" Please tell me what to do to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: Try a different installation disk

Comment: 0x8007045D = ERROR_IO_DEVICE (The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error). Look if the DVD and the HDD are fine.

Comment: :) The error code could be fixed by `Installing Linux`..

Comment: trying with different installation disk dint work and it should most probably be a hdd issue..

Answer (score 4):

That error indicates a problem with the HDD.

> ## Note that the below will erase all data from your hard disk. Make sure this is what you want.

Boot from the install media and instead of install, select "repair your computer" option. 
Select the command prompt at the x sources prompt type:-

DISKPART (press enter) next type:-

LIST DISK (press enter) next type:-

SELECT DISK 0 (after confirming Windows 7 target HD #) (press enter) next type:-

CLEAN (press enter) next type:-

CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY (press enter) next type:-

FORMAT FS=NTFS LABEL="WINDOWS 7" (press enter) next type:-

ACTIVE (press enter) next type:-

EXIT (press enter)

Restart computer with install media, and this time select install.

Comment: the format command takes long time and still on zero percentage for long..how much time it will take to format at 500GB hardisk..

Comment: I get the "'diskpart' is not recognized as an internal or external command" error when I try this on the X:\Sources> prompt. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sure this works for some situations, but I tried it (and everything else) to not avail. In the end I figured out my problem was a bad connection in one of the server's drive bays---simply swapping to a different drive bay got me working in no time.

Answer (score 2):

OK I looked up this error on the Microsoft website and it only happens when there is a failed install like yours, a failed uninstall, damaged file systems, a hard boot(meaning holding the power button until the PC turns off), incomplete formatting of the drive or a virus that was previously on the disk. If your drive is new and you have another PC handy try to plug that drive into the other PC if you can and format it completely and then try to install Windows 7. If that doesn't work I would contact Microsoft for help. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> ## Note that the below will erase all data from your hard disk. Make sure this is what you want.

Boot from the Windows 7 DVD. After the Windows files load into memory, the Windows logo should splash onto the screen. Select the language to install and select **"repair your computer"**. Since the system doesn't have any Windows OS installed, skip must of the screens until you access the "System Recovery Options" window. Select "Command Prompt". The system files are installed on the `X:` drive and your hard drive is `D:` since the Windows starting files were loaded on `C:`.
Format the `D:` drive using the command

```
format D:\ /V
```

Answer **Y** to the warning message and verify the hard drive doesn't have errors. After formatting the hard drive, restart the system and try the Windows installation again.

Comment: I cannot switch to D...  When I type d:, the command prompt hangs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Simply run chkdsk to allocate new sector for the data which is located on bad sectors.

Use the command prompt type following commands

```
chkdsk [name_of_drive][path] /f /v /r /x
```

Examples:

```
C:\Windows\system32>chkdsk d: /f /v /r /x
```

or

```
C:\Windows\system32>chkdsk d:\anyFolder\anyfile.txt /f /v /r /x
```